# App crash for one time after dowloading from google store

Tags: android, ionic-framework, crash

I have just upload a new version of my ionic app to google store.

The application is published... i downloaded the new version of the app from the play store and when i opened it for the first time it crashes...

After the first crash when i open the application again it worked fine...

I looked around in my developer console and found the following stack trace :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzami.zzaf (Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver.onReceive 
(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3201)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17 (Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1684)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:172)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6590)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

I have tried to find similar cases over the net but i didn't find anything understandable, in fact i don't really understand what this error is all about, can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have declared the following dependency in your project.

```
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:<playServiceVersion>'
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:<playServiceVersion>'
     implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

Add this in class that extends Application:

```
  @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
   super.attachBaseContext(base);
   MultiDex.install(this);
 }
```